# Packaging Windows application with Wine in deb and rpm format

Tags: linux, windows, wine, deb

Can I package a Windows application with WINE in .deb and .rpm file?
Just like TeamViewer and Picasa for Linux.

I don't have the source code of the application available, so I cannot compile it using winelib.

Can a installed windows application can be wrapped with all necessary WINE files, so that it runs independently with out installing WINE in a Linux distribution ?

Comment: No;  Without the source code what you want isn't possible.

Comment: If you open a Picasa or TeamViewer DEB file with archive manager you can see how the application has been structured, and you should be able create a similar set of files for your application (I assume RPM files will be similar). Note that each has its own, private WINE installation: this is convenient, because they don't need to keep retesting with every new WINE release, but rather inefficient if you have several such installations in addition to a generic WINE. (By the way, the Picasa 3.9 EXE file installs and runs fine under generic WINE: worth noting, since the last DEB was for 3.0.)